# jQuery image hover with swap and fade

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   // Change the image of hoverable images
   jQuery("#image-map")
        .mouseover(function() { 
            var src = jQuery(this).attr("src").replace(".gif", "_close.gif");
            jQuery(this).attr("src", src);
        })
        .mouseout(function() {
            var src = jQuery(this).attr("src").replace("_close.gif", ".gif");
            jQuery(this).attr("src", src);
        });
});
```

The code above works a treat, but had a quick play with making the image fadeIn with hover and fadeOut on mouseout - any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the fadeIn/fadeOut within the functions you already defined, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Change the image of hoverable images
var openGif = $("#image-map").attr("src");
var closedGif = openGif.replace(".gif", "_close.gif");
$("#image-map")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        $(this).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).attr("src", closedGif);
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).attr("src", openGif);
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

I also changed out the long version jQuery with the shortcut "$". Saves a little typing and bytes on download :)

Comment: Thanks works a treat! i had to use jQuery instead of $ as for some reason does not work in wordpress! but yea i agree i would personally use the shourtcut of $ - do you know of a nice way to make it blend?

Comment: Sure, you can use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //free to use $ in here! :) })` this way the scope of $ is limited to your function, read [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in detail.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the jquery APIs: fadeIn and fadeOut..
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/  http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: Yes i know, but im having issues getting that to work in those functions